# Storing keys with particular pattern on one node in Redis Cluster

Tags: caching, redis

We have a requirement in our Project where customer wants to refresh the Redis Cache on configuration change to remove old data from Cache.
We proposed solution like we can run some scheduler which will scan DB and on recognizing change, it will update cache Or we can join Expire key with keys which we want to expire after sometime.

But, customer doesn't agree and they want to Command line to clear cache, so that on next request Application go to DB for latest values. They want to use `flushall` (which is very very risky)

I was reading RedisCluster where I got to know, If I put certain keys in **{}** redis will store them in same slot for multikey Operations. But the problem is you can't say beforehand on which Redis instance those will be stored.Also, redis can also store other keys on that particular instance, which I don't want.

Can anyone advice some Way I can tell Redis store these keys on this node and rest of the keys scatter around cluster ?

Comment: Why do you say that `flushall` is very very risky? If the entire cache is invalid, that's a legit way to go.

Comment: There will be application data as well along with configuration data. . . We don't want to remove everything from Cache.

Comment: Divide and conquer - separate the two types of data to two different Redis databases and you have it.

Comment: But Redis Cluster doesn't support multiple DBs. Also, I had read Multiple DBs are not recommended to use. Can you please elaborate ?

Comment: You can use a separate cluster, although for configuration data a single instance could very well do as well. Here's more about the concerns with shared databases: https://redislabs.com/blog/benchmark-shared-vs-dedicated-redis-instances